# Drop down menu with different background

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, stylesheet

I have created a CSS drop down menu which can be viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/7ZWnJ/ and code is pasted below.

Is there anyway I can make the drop down section have a different background colour (eg: red), but main heading stays as orange?

Many thanks,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">   
    <head>
        <style>
            #brands {
                height: 430px;
                overflow-y:auto;
                overflow-x:hidden;
                position: absolute;
                width: 460px;
                z-index: 123;
            }
            #menu {
                z-index: 999;
            }
            ul {
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 12px;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                list-style: none;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            ul li {
                position: relative;
            }
            li ul {
                display: none;
                width: 133px;
            }
            ul li a {
                display: block;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #ffffff;
                padding: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
                margin: 0;
                border-top: #f79448 1px solid;
                border-bottom: #f79448 1px solid;
            }
            ul li a:hover {
                z-index: 1000;
                background-color: #F79448;
            }
            li:hover ul {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1000;
                width: 134px;
                margin-left: -3px;
            }
            li:hover li {
                font-size: 12px;
            }
            li:hover a {
                background-color: #F79448;
            }
            li:hover li a:hover {
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="nav-links">
                <td width="128" height="18" align="center" bgcolor="#f79448">
                    <ul id="menu2">
                        <li class="2"><a href="#">OPTION 1</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">OPTION 2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">OPTION 3</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">OPTION 4</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your stylesheet:

```css
#menu2 li ul li a{background:#F00; border-color:#F00}
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZWnJ/2/)

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a dream :-)

Comment: Glad to have helped (:

Answer (score 0):

Through CSS, the best way is to give you heading li tag an id and set all li items colors except the heading as red.

However, if you want to do this as the headings change, and in your JavaScript, you could keep track of which list item is the "head" and every time "head" changes, change the background colors accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your menu is an unordered list (`ul`), you can just add a different class to the elements you want to distinguish (`li`).

I.e. in CSS:

```
li.diff {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

And in HTML:

```
<li class="diff"><a href="#">OPTION 2</a></li>
```